# Understanding Struts2 actions better

Tags: struts2, action

I am trying to learn Struts 2.0 and I am trying to understand the concept of actions better. I  have a form which I would want to be pre-loaded with values. The user can change the values in the JSP and then submit the form, which will lead to a page displaying the data enetered in the form.

I have got it working, but was not sure if my method/logic is correct.

The Struts.xml is as follows:

```
<action name="LoadForm" class="actions.Test" method="execute1">
  <result>/Test.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="ShowResult" class="actions.Test" method="execute2">
  <result>/TestResult.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I am using `prepare()` to preload the values.

When I call `LoadForm.action` in the browser, `Test.jsp` is displayed with preloaded data.

`Test.jsp` has a form whose action is `ShowResult`.

When I submit the form, it navigates to `TestResult.jsp` where I display the values from the form.

Is this a right approach or is there a better way to do it?

Also, I am not sure of why would we need more than 2 execute methods in the Action class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well almost you are right, except one thing you need to understand that prepare method is something like an init method which can help you to init/ prepare data before the framework call the execute or any other method.

Actions in S2 work as model as well Controller same time and its quite possible that one Controller is doing more than one task. e.g we have a Action which is responsible for handling user related processes which includes

1. Creating new user
2. Updating user
3. Checking any information related to user

So in short we need not to have three different Actions  to perform these tasks but we will create a single Action with three methods inside it which will be responsible to handle these tasks.

i hope this might give u an idea

Comment: Thanks for your answer Umesh. I need one more clarification. How do I control when a specific execute method will run? Lets say, I have create(), update(), check() as three methods as per your example, with each leading to a different JSP page. How do I invoke lets say the update() from the form?

Comment: well one simple way is to name your action like this from JSP, say updateUser and when you will map that in your xml file , you can use method tag like <action name="updateUser" class="com.UserAction" method="update"/>.Annotation also provides same way and you can use method property in your action tag and url tag also

Comment: @DeepakMahalingam but you should separate modal object(best practice) from Action using modalDriven interceptor. http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-model-driven-action-example-1.html